# Database reference a DNS name instead of IP address?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I was wondering if it is possible to make my database have a DNS name instead of an IP address with Amazon RDS?  We currently own a website and were wondering if there was a solution to have something like db.website.com refer to our Amazon Web Services database?  Is this possible?

Comment: Your question is vague. But I'll try to guess what you needed. `mysql` does support DNS names. You will need to buy a domain name unless you already own one. Register the IP address in your domain and configure `mysql` and change `sql` codes to use DNS names. I'd recommend getting an elastic IP for your Amazon RDS so the Public IP will persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a database instance is launched under Amazon RDS (Relational Database Service), an endpoint is provided in the form of:

```
db.crwobkqad31a.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306
```

If you wish to apply a more friendly DNS name, **configure a `CNAME` record in your DNS server** (eg Amazon Route 53) that maps the friendly name (eg `db.website.com`) to the database endpoint.

The DNS name will resolve to an IP address. If the database is publicly-accessible and the name is resolved outside your Amazon VPC, a public IP address will be returned. If the name is resolved within your Amazon VPC, a private IP address will be returned.

You will typically want to protect your database from outside access by placing it into a private subnet. It is unusual to want to give end-users direct access to a database (which I'm assuming you want to do, given the desire for a friendly DNS name), but that is your choice.

Comment: "It is unusual to want to give end-users direct access to a database (which I'm assuming you want to do, given the desire for a friendly DNS name)" It might just be wanting to hard-code "db.example.com" into an app and not having to worry about pushing out an update to the code if the database endpoint changes.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if it is possible to make my database have a DNS name instead of an IP address with Amazon RDS?

Not only can you, but you **must**. Your RDS will have an endpoint like `something.random-string.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com`. Correcting directly to its IPs is dangerous as the server's IP may change unexpectedly (if the server is modified, scaled, has an issue, or fails over).

You can use a `CNAME` pointed at your RDS endpoint, if you like, to use something like `db.example.com` instead of your RDS endpoint.